# cant remove background image from master style sheet

Tags: css

Our application has a master .css common for all our pages and we are not allowed to change anything in this file.

We have an entry there as follows:

```
ul li{display:block;padding:0 0 0.5em 15px;margin:0 0 0 0;background:url(../images/bullet.gif) top left no-repeat;}
```

I am implementing predictive search on one of the jsp-s and I have a specific css file for this purpose which is as follows

```
.ac_results {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.ac_results ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-position: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: disc inside;
}

.ac_results li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    /* 
        if width will be 100% horizontal scrollbar will apear 
        when scroll mode will be used
    */
    /*width: 100%;*/ 
    font: menu;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* 
    it is very important, if line-height not setted or setted 
    in relative units scroll will be broken in firefox
    */
    line-height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ac_loading {
    background: white url('indicator.gif') right center no-repeat;
}

.ac_odd {
    background-color: #eee;
 }

.ac_over {
    background-color: #0A246A;
    color: white;
}
```

My problem is that I am unable to remove this `bullet.gif` from my current predictive search list . If I add background: none I am loosing all the existing background colours.
How can I stop this `bullet.gif` to appear in my list.

**PLEASE NOTE :** I tried with `background-image:none;` also and it did not work, the `bullet.gif` is still coming up in my search list :(

Regards, M

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `background: none` try:

```
background-image: none
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added 
        background-image:none; 
to all the blocks but no luck :-(

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
 background-image:none;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added background-image:none; to all the blocks but no luck :-(

Comment: I will suggest you to inspect your page with firebug and try using background-image:none; on different css selector. more accurate css selector will work like .wrapper_div ul li{background-image:none;}